# Ignoring a specific file when using require.js

Tags: requirejs

requirejs parses JS files as text and builds a tree of all the requires...

It then injects includes into the head of an HTML file.

In a particular context I need to ignore a particular file so e.g. if it sees this it won't be added to the HTML file:

`const { mixinService } = require("devtools/shared/mixinService");`

I need to know how to do this because in one context I need the file but in another it will break all of my components.

Let me describe the different contexts: I work at Mozilla on the Firefox browser. Scripts can run in a privileged JS environment, where they have access to special APIs or they can run in content (like a regular webpage).

The mixinService uses some of those privileged APIs so it is incompatible with content scripts so the contexts are privileged and content. We need to ignore the require when running in the content process.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that you can use define for this so in my case it looks like this:

```
define("devtools/shared/mixinService", {
  mixinService: {
    mixins: []
  }
});

require.config({
  baseUrl: "resource://devtools-client-jsonview/",
  paths: {
    "devtools/client/shared": "resource://devtools-client-shared",
    "devtools/shared": "resource://devtools/shared",
    "devtools/client/shared/vendor/react":
      JSONView.debug
      ? "resource://devtools-client-shared/vendor/react-dev"
      : "resource://devtools-client-shared/vendor/react"
  }
});

// Load the main panel module
requirejs(["json-viewer"]);
```

Easy when you know how.